# Польза от использования extern?

Tags: c++

Можно ли извлечь какую-нибудь пользу от использования `extern` в с++? Допустим, например, что программа не использует глобальные переменные. Первая мысль что приходит на ум, так это попытаться использовать extern для использования функций, не объявляя при этом их в заголовке (вероятно это увеличит скорость компиляции - но ведь и может замедлить например скорость линковки). В общем немного не понятно, может это просто рудимент от с, и в с++ не имеет большого смысла.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55664/discussion-on-question-by-lmtinytoon----extern).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Этот вопрос в общем-то отвечен в документации и на форуме http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/21368/

Во-первых. понятие "польза" здесь неприменимо. Ключевое слово extern выполняет функции, иначе не достижимые другими средствами. Извините, но в языке редко остается что-то лишнее просто так (ключевое слово register - очень особый случай)

Ключевое слово extern используется в трех случаях

1. Для описания статического хранилища со спецификатором внешнего связывания.
2. Для указания языка, "С" или "С++". Это влияет на то, происходит ли искажение имен для С++ или нет). Следует учитывать, что это не предполагает что код компилируется "как в Си".
3. Декларация явной инстанциации шаблона типа (extern template).До С++11 это было только расширением языка (оригинально - компиляторов IBM), при использовании некоторых компиляторов extern не требовался. Его разрешено использовать только один раз для данного списка аргументов.

   `extern template сlass-name < argument-list >;`

> An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) skips implicit instantiation step: the code that would otherwise cause an
>   implicit instantiation instead uses the explicit instantiation
>   definition provided elsewhere (resulting in link errors if no such
>   instantiation exists). This can be used to reduce compilation times by
>   explicitly declaring a template instantiation in all but one of the
>   source files using it, and explicitly defining it in the remaining
>   file (С++11).

Декларация явной инстанциации шаблона (внешний шаблон) позволяет пропустить шаг неявного создания кода шаблона и вместо этого использовать экземпляр шаблона, описанный где-то еще (что  привело бы к ошибкам редактора связей, если таковая 
не была произведена). В С++ декларация явной специализации во всех файлах
исходных текстов кроме одного, где он будет определен полностью, может позволить сэкономить время компиляции.

Comment: Просто блестяще, именно то, что я и искал

Comment: Не совсем понятна фраза "до С++11 это записывалось без extern". К чему именно она относится? Explicit specialization declaration (c `extern`) - это *дополнительная* фича в С++11, ее не было до C++11 поэтому "до С++11 записываться без extern" она никак не могла - ее просто не было. Сама же explicit specialization как записывалась без `extern` до С++11, так и записывается без `extern` в С++11 - тут ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Кстати, а как в ваши "три случая" вписывается вариант `extern const int = 5;`? "Линкования из внешнего источника нет" - источник как раз таки здесь. Остальные варианты тоже ни при чем...

Comment: **Явная специализация шаблона типа** записывалась без extern. В @Ant. Эти "мои" три варианта из стандарта. `extern const int = 5;` что-то пропущено, имя переменной я полагаю? Это первый вариант.  С++ extern был добавлен к специализации типа для более прозрачного синтаксиса, так первое назначение этого дейсвия - использование внешнего источника. Старый синтакис тем не менее поддерживается. > она никак не могла - ее просто не было.< фактическая ошибка, это существовало очень давно, в первую очередь в компиляторе C++ IBM.  Я этим пользовался в VS2003 и возможно еще в VS6

Comment: @Swift: Это у вас какая-то каша. Во-первых, речь идет не о явной специализации, а о явной **инстанциации**. Во-вторых, сама явная инстанциация шаблона как записывалась без `extern`, так и записывается без `extern` в С++11. Здесь абсолютно ничего не поменялось. В С++11 добавилась возможность *предварительно объявлять* явные инстанциации. И вот для этого был введен синтаксис с `extern template class <argument list>` (у вас, кстати, в ответе пропущено `template`). Не надо путать саму инстанциацию, и ее *объявление*.

Comment: Так что никакого "старого" или "нового" синтаксиса тут нет - есть *расширение* функцональности explicit instantiation, для которого появилась совершенно новая фича языка с совершенно новым синтаксисом, основанным на `extern`. Объявление explicit instatiation является опциональным (для ускорения компиляции). Объявление explicit instatiation не является explicit instatiation само по себе. Это лишь *объявление*. Сама же explicit instantiation делается точно так же, как и всегда - никакого `extern`.

Comment: @AnT C instantiation согласен, в 90-х это так не называли и в дествительности путали то и другое , так изначально одно без другого не происходило. Сейчас я говорю в 9 из 10 случаев по-английски, а это слово  не словарное, так что проблемы с "современным жаргоном" (с его вводом даже проблемы). Насчет новой функциональности не понял, она работает так как и работала - позволяет создать код шаблона без его использования. Просто раньше запись без extern в той ситуации работала как декларация extern template в С++11.

Comment: @AnT По поводу констант: До переменной , определенной как `const int  i = 5;` в С++ нельзя достучаться с помощью описания `extern const int  i;` (в С  можно). У всех const локальная линковка по  умолчанию, поэтому можно писать `extern const int  i = 5;` для декларации внешней. Формально появления такого определения в нескольких модулях приведет к ошибке повторяющихся символов в С++, однако можно описать так: `extern const int  i; const int  i = 5;` а в другом модуле - `extern const int  i;`

Comment: @Swift: Еще раз по шагам: для создания кода шаблона без его использования в С++ есть **explicit instantiation** с синтаксисом `template class <arg>`. Explicit instantiation существует в С++ уже давно. Ее синтаксис не менялся ни до С++11, ни после. Другого синтаксиса для explicit instantiation в С++ нет. Explicit instantiation всегда делается в одном из файлов реализации. Но начиная с С++11 вы можете также *дополнительно указать в заголовочном файле* **explicit instantiation declaration** (заметьте разницу в терминах) для вашей explicit instantiation через `extern template class <arg>`.

Comment: То есть сама explicit instantiation по-прежнему сидит в одном из файлов реализации, а *предварительное объявление* (declaration) для нее со словом `extern` сидит в заголовочном файле. Наличие объявления теоретически может ускорить компиляцию. Но в любом случае explicit instantiation declaration - опционально. Именно возможность сделать explicit instantiation declaration является новой фичей С++11 с новым синтаксисом. Сама же explicit instantiation сохранила свой старый синтаксис и ничего в этом отношении в С++11 не менялось.

Comment: По поводу `extern const int i = 5;` - не надо мне рассказывать как линкуются по умолчанию `const` объекты в С++ - я сам вам про это с радостью расскажу. Мой вопрос вполне конкретен: под какой из ваших трех вариантов попадает `extern const int i = 5;`? Никакой "линковки из внешнего источника" в этом случае нет.

Comment: @AnT эм, это и есть разрешение линковки из внешнего источника. как с любой глобальной переменной

Comment: @AnT: Не совсем понял. Ваш пункт 1 сформулирован так "...линкуемого из внешнего источника, в этом оно аналогично описанию прототипа функции." Я так понял, что вы хотели сказать, что объявление с `extern` не является *определением*, а является лишь ссылкой на "внешний источник". Но `extern const int i = 5;` *является* определением, как и `extern int a = 42;`. В чем в этих случаях заключается аналогия с "описанием прототипа функции"?

Comment: @AnT определения является описанием, но не наоборот, нет противоречия. extern const int i = 5; так как есть инициализатор, extern const int i; будет описанием.Более точным, если использовать Ваш перевод терминов, будет сказать что это определение со спицификатором внешнего связывания.

Comment: @Swift: Совершено верно. Не совсем понимаю, зачем вы это здесь привели. Я еще повторю свой вопрос: Я так понял, что вы хотели сказать, что объявление с `extern` *не является определением*, а является лишь ссылкой на "внешний источник". Это так? Если вы хотели сказать не это, то тогда поясните, что именно вы хотели сказать и где именно тут аналогия с "описанием прототипа функции"?

Comment: @AnT нет, я этого не хотел сказать. С описанием прототипа функции аналогично а структура и использование, как это определялось  в синтаксических диаграммах. Прототип функции тоже не является _ссылкой_ он являлся описанием. Описание extern переменной   с посл дующим инициализатором является определением переменной, прототип функции с последующим телом - определением функции. И то , и другое может иметь спецификатор extern.

Answer (score 3):

Чаще всего **extern** используется для неявного совместного доступа к общим данным из разных модулей программы. Часто применяется при работе плохо спроектированными библиотеками. Проще создать глобальную переменную и подцепить ее через extern, чем писать несколько акцессоров.

Единственным его преимуществом является только то, что на обмен данными не тратится дополнительное время, так как данные всегда под рукой у каждого модуля, и не требуется никакой синхронизации (только в однопоточном режиме). В современных реалиях оправдать использование extern можно только в ПО для микроконтроллеров, и только в исключительных ситуациях, когда быстродействие действительно важно.

Его использование может сильно запутать стуктуру программы и привести к спагетти коду. Лучше придерживаться такого правила: если можно обойтись без extern, то нужно без него обойтись.

Comment: рассматриваете только одно использование extern  из 4х (если считать  расширение ставшее частью стандарта в С++) возможных. Вообще-то, если считать только число используемых ключевых слов, то самое распространенное использование  - это связывание с функциями библиотек. а не с глобальными переменными. Больше похоже что вы просто высказали свое мнение о функционале, чему  не место на SO. ЗЫ: ПО для микроконтроллеров и ПЛИС до сих пор пишется на С, так как оно слишком неабстрактно, там extern действительно часто встречается